# UWP C# WebView AddWebAllowedObject - Javascript error, scriptprojectionhost error in edgehtml.dll

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I have a Windows 10 UWP C# app which has a WebView-Control. I am using the WebView.AddWebAllowedObject method to inject my own JavaScript functions. The class is defined as a separate universal windows runtime component project. The native object is then inserted in the OnNavigationStarting event handler.

Everything works fine in debug mode. But when the solution is built and run in release mode, The Windows runtime component is not working in WebView and I see the following error in output window

"onecoreuap\inetcore\lib\scriptprojectionhost\scripthostcontext.cxx(318)\edgehtml.dll!146477A0: (caller: 1445B8EE) LogHr(2) tid(3eb8) 80004005 Unspecified error"

Below is how I defined the class for the  Windows Runtime component.

```
[AllowForWeb, ComVisible(true)]
[MarshalingBehavior(MarshalingType.Agile)]
public sealed class MyWebViewHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public event NotifyAppHandler NotifyAppEvent;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));

        }

    }

   public void myMouseOverEvent(string webViewEventData)
    {
        try
        {
            Href = webViewEventData;
            MyWebViewEventData = webViewEventData;
            NotifyAppEvent.Invoke(MyWebViewEventData);
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
     }

    string _myWebViewEventData;
    public string MyWebViewEventData
    {
        get { return this._myWebViewEventData; }
        set
        {
          this._myWebViewEventData = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("MyWebViewEventData");
        }
    }

   public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

The runtime object is then initialized globally

```
 public MyWebViewHandler winRTObject = new MyWebViewHandler();
```

In the WebView.NavigationStarting event handler I call the Webview.InvokeScriptAsync as follows.

```
 myWebView.AddWebAllowedObject("NotifyApp", winRTObject);
```

In the WebView.DOMContentLoaded event handler I call the Webview.InvokeScriptAsync as follows.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("document.addEventListener");
sb.Append("(");
sb.Append("\"mouseover\",");
sb.Append(" function (e) ");
sb.Append("{");
sb.Append(" var attrHref = e.target.getAttribute(\"href\");" +
         " NotifyApp.myMouseOverEvent(attrHref);"
          );
sb.Append("}");
sb.Append(");");

string function = sb;
await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { function });
```

The app used to run fine in release mode and was published in Windows store earlier this year.

I am not sure if this error has something to do with Win 10 creator's update.

Below is the error again. The runtime component methods are not firing. My dev machine is running Window 10 creator update, Visual Studio 2017, 15.2 (26430.12)

"onecoreuap\inetcore\lib\scriptprojectionhost\scripthostcontext.cxx(318)\edgehtml.dll!146477A0: (caller: 1445B8EE) LogHr(2) tid(3eb8) 80004005 Unspecified error"

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Adding relative code for NotifyAppHandler and PropertyChangedEventHandler

```
winRTObject.PropertyChanged += WinRTObject_PropertyChanged;
winRTObject.NotifyAppEvent += WinRTObject_NotifyAppEvent;

...
 private  void WinRTObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)  
    {
      try
        {
           string  elementValue = winRTObject.Href
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }   

private  void WinRTObject_NotifyAppEvent(string eventData)
 {
    try
    {           
       string elementValue = eventData;
     ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

**Update 1**

I downgraded the NuGet package  "Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" from version 5.3.4 to to 5.2.3 and the problem was resolved.

Note:   Visual Studio 2017, 15.2 (26430.12) has package 5.2.3 in Blank UWP App template.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with the same environments testing on my side. Please also provide 'NotifyAppHandler' relative code snippet and I 'll try again. If conveniently, a [mcve] required.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have included 'NotifyAppHandler' relative code snippet . I will create a minimal example later today.

Comment: I think you will be able to reproduce the problem if you update the NuGet package "Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" to version 5.3.0 and above.   I downgraded the package version to 5.2.3 and the problem was resolved.  Visual Studio 2017, 15.2 (26430.12) has package 5.2.3 in Blank UWP App template.